# Error: Main class cannot be initialized Cause: java.long.NoClassDefFoundError: net/dv8tion/jda/api/EmbedBuilder

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, discord-jda

when I wanted to update my bot I got exactly this error message as it says in the title `'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDABuilder'` and I really have no idea what could be so big the error right now, because I didn't get an error message anywhere in a class and I don't really know where that problem could be except in the pom.xml, so I wanted to ask for help.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>GamerSucht</groupId>
    <artifactId>GamerSucht</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>9</source>
                    <target>9</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0_247</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>club.minnced</groupId>
                    <artifactId>opus-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.40.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.oshi</groupId>
            <artifactId>oshi-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
            <version>5.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>5.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sedmelluq</groupId>
            <artifactId>lavaplayer</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.63</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google</groupId>
            <artifactId>google</artifactId>
            <version>5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jagrosh</groupId>
            <artifactId>jda-utilities</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rethinkdb</groupId>
            <artifactId>rethinkdb-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.jodah/expiringmap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.jodah</groupId>
            <artifactId>expiringmap</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>GamerSucht</groupId>
            <artifactId>GamerSucht</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have tried to update the dependencies but still get the same error message

Answer (score 0):

I simply added a compiler which fixed the problem

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>main.java.de.emir.main.Main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```